# Match lists and write result to new list

Tags: python, list

I have a problem matching lists in python.

```
list1 = [["id1","string1","string2"],["id2","string3","string4"]]
list2 =   [["id1","string1","string2", "string3"],["id3","string4","string5", "string6"]]
```

I want something like this

```
list3 = [["id1", "string1", "string2", "string3"],["id2","string3","string4"],["id3","string4","string5", "string6"]]
```

if an id from list1 is in list2 then write the element from list2 (e.g. `["id1","string1","string2"]`) to a new list. If it's not in the list take the element from list1 and write it to the new list. At the end the result should look something like this

I tried it this way

```
for p in list1:
   for d in list2:
       if ( (p[0] in list2)):
          list3.append(d)
          next
       else:
          list3.append(p)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem then?

Comment: Please demonstrate that you have atleast made an effort with some code and show where you are struggling

Comment: Does the order of elements in the output matter?

Comment: The order doesn't matter. I added an example what I tried, but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter then the best way is to convert them to dictionaries and match them like this

```
dict1 = {item[0]: item for item in list1}
dict2 = {item[0]: item for item in list2}
print [dict2.get(item, dict1.get(item)) for item in dict1.viewkeys() | dict2]
```

**Output**

```
[['id2', 'string3', 'string4'],
 ['id3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6'],
 ['id1', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3']]
```

If you are using Python 3.x, then use [`dict.keys`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) instead of [`dict.viewkeys`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys), like this

```
print([dict2.get(item, dict1.get(item)) for item in dict1.keys() | dict2])
```

The same can be written like this

```
[dict2.get(item) or dict1.get(item) for item in dict1.keys() | dict2]
```

Comment: how does bitwise operator work here? ps. OK, got it, set arithmetics for view

Comment: @m.wasowski When it is used with set like objects, it works as set union operator :)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to transform your lists to dicts, which is easier to do the job, e.g.:

```
In [259]: list1 = [["id1","string1","string2"],["id2","string3","string4"]]

In [260]: {i[0]:i[1:] for i in list1}
Out[260]: {'id1': ['string1', 'string2'], 'id2': ['string3', 'string4']}
```

then you can check if the keys (namely your `id`s) in the 1st dict are in the 2nd dict:

```
In [270]: d1 = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in list1}

In [271]: d2 = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in list2}

In [272]: d1.update(d2)

In [273]: d1
Out[273]: 
{'id1': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
 'id2': ['string3', 'string4'],
 'id3': ['string4', 'string5', 'string6']}
```

If you want to convert it back to list anyway:

```
In [275]: [[k]+d1[k] for k in d1]
Out[275]: 
[['id2', 'string3', 'string4'],
 ['id3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6'],
 ['id1', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3']]
```